# Android RestTemplate j_spring_security_check not redirecting

Tags: android, spring-security, resttemplate

In the Android app I'm working on I am using RestTemplate to post a request to log in (Spring Security):

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("j_username", uname);
headers.add("j_password", password);
headers.add("submit", "Login");
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(null, headers);
ResponseEntity<String> reply = restTemplate.exchange(baseUrl + "/j_spring_security_check", HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
```

The reply:

```
<302 Found,{Date=[Wed, 30 Sep 2015 08:10:15 GMT], Server=[Apache-Coyote/1.1], Location=[http://192.168.100.81/rest/loginstatus;jsessionid=A63589BF9985296C42A8FC49C858F2AA], Content-Length=[0], Set-Cookie=[JSESSIONID=A63589BF9985296C42A8FC49C858F2AA; Path=/], Keep-Alive=[timeout=5, max=100], Connection=[Keep-Alive], X-Android-Sent-Millis=[1443600616746], X-Android-Received-Millis=[1443600616756]}>
```

As you can see, it is supposed to redirect to location, but it's not. I understand the default behaviour is to redirect only on GET requests.

How can I make this request follow the redirect? I've seen a lot of solutions using Apache's HttpClient, which is removed in API 23.

I guess a workaround is to post another request to the redirect location myself, but I hope there is a better solution.

Comment: j_spring_security_check is intended for form submissions, it is not recommended for REST.

Answer (score 0):

To make `RestTemplate` always follow redirects:

```java
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory() {
    @Override
    protected void prepareConnection(HttpURLConnection connection, String httpMethod) throws IOException
    {
        super.prepareConnection(connection, httpMethod);
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
    }
});
```

**Update:** You construct the `HttpEntity` wrong, `j_username` etc are not headers. You probably want:

```java
MultiValueMap<String, String> form = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
form.add("j_username", uname);
form.add("j_password", password);
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> entity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(form, null);
```

Comment: This results in an error code 400 bad request. It also takes a very long time for the response to arrive.